# Log4j send email to multiple users via properties

Tags: java, email, smtp, log4j

I am trying to configure my log4j properties file in order to send emails when are error occurs. I have it working for one person, and am receiving the emails whenever an error occurs. However, I want to have the emails be sent to multiple people on my team when something happens. Is there a way to configure this? Here is my log file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, sendMail
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR

log4j.appender.sendMail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender  
log4j.appender.sendMail.Threshold=WARN  
log4j.appender.sendMail.To=blbla@asdf.com
log4j.appender.sendMail.From=blba@asdf.com  
log4j.appender.sendMail.SMTPHost=smtp.asdf.asdf.com
log4j.appender.sendMail.Subject=Error Log Message  
log4j.appender.sendMail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.sendMail.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n  
log4j.appender.sendMail.BufferSize=1
```

I have tried adding a comma after the 'To' command and adding another email address, but that person does not receive it. Any ideas on how I can configure this file to send the errors to multiple people?

Comment: a comma after the 'TO' command, or after the email address? the comma should be a delimiter per email address

Comment: I put a comma after the 'to' command like so
'log4j.appender.sendMail.To=blbla@asdf.com, qwer@asdfs.com' and it did not send the email to the second person. Only the first got it.

Comment: what version of log4j are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is considered the correct way to use multiple appends, in log4j1.2.x:

```
log4j.appender.MailAppender.To=bob@bob.com,jill@jill.com,dave@dave.com
```

Source 1: [Old archives of Log4j](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/200405.mbox/%3C7395B46C07F8D51182AE000629570CC4B2E516@ike.local.anstat.com.au%3E)

Source 2: [Log4j wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/SMTPAppender)

Comment: I will try it without the white space and see how that works. Thanks for the tip. I will also try the other email separatly and see if my teammate gets that. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Eric if this does not work, provide me with the version you are using for log4j so i can investigate further

Comment: How to do it in xml file?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can skip the problem altogether by using a mail alias or a mailing list instead of a list of mail addresses here.

This seams to have the advantage that is is probably easier to maintain than modifying your property-file each time.